# Script runs great in VSCode, but hangs in Powershell ISE and command prompt

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have a script that is on the complex side. It registers an objectevent and has a bunch of embedded C# code.

It works great in the VSCode debugger

But in both the Powershell ISE and a powershell command prompt, it hangs part way through running the action in the objectevent.

From some other threads with a similar smell, I have confirmed that all three powershell run time environments (VSCode debugger, Powershell cmd prompt and Powershell ISE) all are running in STA mode:

```
    PS C:\Users\sam> [System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.GetApartmentState()

STA
```

All three enviroments report the following version information:

```
PS C:\Users\sam> $PSVersionTable


Name                           Value                                           
----                           -----                                           
PSVersion                      5.1.22000.282                                   
PSEdition                      Desktop                                         
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                         
BuildVersion                   10.0.22000.282                                  
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                 
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                             
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                             
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

What is the delta in these environments that I should chase?

Comment: In VS Code, what version of Powershell are you running in?  And what version of PowerShell are you using in your console ("powershell command prompt")?

Comment: @DarkMoon Thanks! OP enhanced

Comment: Is it hanging on the C# code? Do you have any "Write-Output" in your script so you can see where it hangs? And I haven't used C# much in my scripts, but I believe it loads the script, compiles the C# code, then begins running the script, so it'd be good to know if it's even compiling in the first place, or hanging on execution. I'm ignoring ISE as I haven't used it since it was retired, but AFAIK, the console that the debugger uses in VS Code should be the system-installed one, so there shouldn't really be much of a difference.

Comment: [1] from what i can tell, the PoSh host in VSCode is not the same as the one in windows powershell.exe ... so there may be an obscure difference that is biting you. i don't know how to pinpoint that beyond normal detailed logging and debugging steps.  ///// [2] as DarkMoon mentioned, you need to find out exactly where your code is hanging. [*grin*]

Comment: From previous questions I'm guessing you're running into some sort of race condition with events raised by a `FileSystemWatcher` - it's very hard to troubleshoot without seeing what you're actually trying to do. Is there any chance you could [provide an MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or post the event action scriptblock that appears to hang?