# Powershell: Debugging: VSCode behavior not consistent with powershell prompt

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

I have experienced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71505053/147637), and have seen in discussions [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1856#issuecomment-511507563), and [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1856#issuecomment-511611219) (quote: "good as PowerShell is and as good as vscode is, together they actually stink ") that:

There is a material delta between how a powershell script runs (and debugs) in VSCode vs outside VSCode.

**Question:**
Where can I find a write up that explains the delta and how to manage for it?

**Context:**
I currently have code that runs fine within VSCode but fails outside, and man is it frustrating!